# Google Action certification taked too long

Tags: actions-on-google

We are a smart home product development company and we have been working on voice assistants integration and Google action is actually part of our assistant integration. We developed and submitted our initial google action for the certification that will be shipped with our product to the customers. As per in the action console release page, they state the review may take 5-7 days and will be notified via an email once review is completed but it's been longer than said days now, we didn't hear back anything yet. We are unable to find any support email to google action for direct inquiry hence we don't have any clues what's the actual status with our google action. Is there any support email, we can directly reach out to google action support rep like in Alexa? The critical part is our marketing team has planned to release the product within next couple of weeks. So, we have to make sure the google action developed is on Live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dedicated page for actions that are stuck in review, but it also offers some other support options.

https://support.google.com/actions-console/contact/support

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. Google action support team responded quickly to the inquiry submitted using the link.